# Firebase Analytics with Amazon In-App purchasing

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, amazon-in-app-purchase

Looking at moving from Google Analytics to Firebase. I note that it states it automatically collects in-app purchase data for IOS and Google Play but I would also look to get data from Amazon Appstore and Galaxy Apps In-App purchases. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics for Firebase's data for in_app_purchases for android app comes from Google Play after the [linkage](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6392038?hl=en&ref_topic=6317497) has been established in between Google Play and Firebase. For iOS app, it is tracked after the SDK has been put in place.

If you want to track data of in_app_purchases from Amazon and Galaxy app stores, send a [feature request to Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: I can of course do this but it rather forces me to stick with traditional Google Analytics in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

For other kind of in_app_purchases, you can try to log **ecommerce_purchase** events which is also a conversion event similar to IAP event and it also counts automatically to the **lifetime value** just like IAP. On the callback when your users have finished a transaction, you can log the value of the product and the currency of it. See more details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I had considered eCommerce but as we wish to get all purchases on a single report, we would end up double counting the Apple and Google purchases. Also, I am sure i am being stupid, but I cannot see on eCommerce event how you indicate which item has been purchased!

Comment: I think you can provide the item's information in the parameters and you can use custom parameters to see them in the report or Big Query to get all the data you need.